# Has Russia invaded Ukraine?

Tags: war, military, russia, ukraine

The [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/11/13/world/europe/ukraine-russia-military-border-nato.html) and many other media have reported that Russia invaded Ukraine:

> A senior NATO official confirmed on Wednesday what Ukrainian military officials and monitors from the Organization for Security and Cooperation in Europe have been saying for days now: Russian troops and military equipment are crossing the border into Ukraine, seemingly preparing for renewed military action, though what exactly remains unclear.

However, Russia denies it completely. From [RT.com](http://rt.com/news/204895-russia-ukraine-military-nato/):

> Russia has denied NATO claims that its army has crossed into eastern Ukraine in the past few days, calling them groundless, the Defense Ministry said.
>
> “We have stopped paying attention to the groundless accusations made by NATO’s Supreme Allied Commander in Europe, US General Philip Breedlove, of the ‘observed’ Russian military columns allegedly invading Ukraine,” said Defense Ministry official representative, General-Major Igor Konashenkov on Wednesday.
>
> He gave a reminder of earlier and similar NATO claims, which have not been backed by any evidence.
>
> “[We have] repeatedly stressed that there was and is no evidence supporting Brussels’ regular trumpeting over the alleged presence of Russian forces in Ukraine,” Konashenkov said.

Is there any evidence aside from NATO that Russia has sent its military into Ukraine?

Comment: If reports from NATO, OSCE, and the Ukraine aren't sufficient evidence, then short of an admission from Russia, I don't know what would be.  You've eliminated pretty much everyone who's in a position to provide evidence.

Comment: @Mark: there is quite some impressive investigative journalism being conducted on Ukraine, such as https://news.vice.com/show/russian-roulette or https://www.bellingcat.com/tag/ukraine/. So, luckily we don't have to rely on official sources only, and I suspect that NATO and Ukraine are not always credible anyway, or at least frame their information in a way which suits their interests. If I had more time I would read these sources in detail and write an answer.

Comment: Russia doesn't "send" its military into the Ukraine: individuals choose/volunteer to go there during their holiday...

Comment: @ChrisW, for a given definition of "choose" and "volunteer". And "holiday".

Comment: The text of the Minsk cease-fire protocol might be relevant here, since it was agreed to in particular by the Russian federation. Item 9 reads: "All foreign militarized formations, military equipment and militants and mercenaries are to exit the territory of Ukraine under OSCE monitoring." Judge for yourself how close this comes to the Russian side admitting an invasion. See http://www.kyivpost.com/content/ukraine/english-language-translation-of-the-sept-5-cease-fire-memorandum-in-minsk-365460.html

Comment: @ChrisW : Isn't it lovely how Russian militarymen are so attached to their guns and tanks that they bring them on holiday ?

Comment: The corpus of evidence of Russian army intervening in Donbass is quite extensive. Here's a number of open-data investigations with photo and video evidence of their presence in Donbass: https://informnapalm.org/db/russian-aggression/#lang=en&page=m_unit. The amount of units speaks for itself, each backed by evidence.